# How to use Koala Facebook Graph API?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, hash, hashmap

I am a Rails newbie. I want to use Koala's Graph API.

In my controller

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new('myFacebookAccessToken')
@hello = @graph.get_object("my.Name")
```

When I do this, I get something like this

```
{
"id"=>"123456", 
"name"=>"First Middle Last", 
"first_name"=>"First", 
"middle_name"=>"Middle", 
"last_name"=>"Last", 
"link"=>"http://www.facebook.com/MyName", 
"username"=>"my.name", 
"birthday"=>"12/12/1212", 
"hometown"=>{"id"=>"115200305133358163", "name"=>"City, State"}, "location"=>{"id"=>"1054648928202133335", "name"=>"City, State"}, 
"bio"=>"This is my awesome Bio.", 
"quotes"=>"I am the master of my fate; I am the captain of my soul. - William Ernest Henley\r\n\r\n"Don't go around saying the world owes you a living. The world owes you nothing. It was here first.\" - Mark Twain", 
"work"=>[{"employer"=>{"id"=>"100751133333", "name"=>"Company1"}, "position"=>{"id"=>"105763693332790962", "name"=>"Position1"}, "start_date"=>"2010-08", "end_date"=>"2011-07"}],
"sports"=>[{"id"=>"104019549633137", "name"=>"Sport1"}, {"id"=>"103992339636529", "name"=>"Sport2"}], 
"favorite_teams"=>[{"id"=>"105467226133353743", "name"=>"Fav1"}, {"id"=>"19031343444432369133", "name"=>"Fav2"}, {"id"=>"98027790139333", "name"=>"Fav3"}, {"id"=>"104055132963393331", "name"=>"Fav4"}, {"id"=>"191744431437533310", "name"=>"Fav5"}], 
"favorite_athletes"=>[{"id"=>"10836600585799922", "name"=>"Fava1"}, {"id"=>"18995689436787722", "name"=>"Fava2"}, {"id"=>"11156342219404022", "name"=>"Fava4"}, {"id"=>"11169998212279347", "name"=>"Fava5"}, {"id"=>"122326564475039", "name"=>"Fava6"}], 
"inspirational_people"=>[{"id"=>"16383141733798", "name"=>"Fava7"}, {"id"=>"113529011990793335", "name"=>"fava8"}, {"id"=>"112032333138809855566", "name"=>"Fava9"}, {"id"=>"10810367588423324", "name"=>"Fava10"}], 
"education"=>[{"school"=>{"id"=>"13478880321332322233663", "name"=>"School1"}, "type"=>"High School", "with"=>[{"id"=>"1401052755", "name"=>"Friend1"}]}, {"school"=>{"id"=>"11482777188037224", "name"=>"School2"}, "year"=>{"id"=>"138383069535219", "name"=>"2005"}, "type"=>"High School"}, {"school"=>{"id"=>"10604484633093514", "name"=>"School3"}, "year"=>{"id"=>"142963519060927", "name"=>"2010"}, "concentration"=>[{"id"=>"10407695629335773", "name"=>"c1"}], "type"=>"College"}, {"school"=>{"id"=>"22030497466330708", "name"=>"School4"}, "degree"=>{"id"=>"19233130157477979", "name"=>"c3"}, "year"=>{"id"=>"201638419856163", "name"=>"2011"}, "type"=>"Graduate School"}], 
"gender"=>"male", 
"interested_in"=>["female"], 
"relationship_status"=>"Single", 
"religion"=>"Religion1", 
"political"=>"Political1", 
"email"=>"somename@somecompany.com", 
"timezone"=>-8, 
"locale"=>"en_US", 
"languages"=>[{"id"=>"10605952233759137", "name"=>"English"}, {"id"=>"10337617475934611", "name"=>"L2"}, {"id"=>"11296944428713061", "name"=>"L3"}], 
"verified"=>true,
"updated_time"=>"2012-02-24T04:18:05+0000"
}
```

How do I show this entire hash in the view in a good format?

This is what I did from what ever I learnt.. 
In my view

```
<% @hello.each do |key, value| %>
<li><%=h "#{key.to_s} : #{value.to_s}" %></li>
<% end %>
```

This will get the entire thing converted to a list... It works awesome if its just one key.. but how to work with multiple keys and show only the information... something like
when it outputs `hometown : City, State` rather than something like

```
hometown : {"id"=>"115200305133358163", "name"=>"City, State"}
```

Also for education if I just say `education[school][name]` to display list of schools attended?

The error i get is `can't convert String into Integer`

I also tried to do this in my controller, but I get the same error..

```
@fav_teams = @hello["favorite_teams"]["name"]
```

Also, how can I **save all these to the database**.. something like just the list of all schools.. not their id no's?

**Update:**

The way I plan to save to my database is.. lets say for a user model, i want to save to database as :facebook_id, :facebook_name, :facebook_firstname, ...., :facebook_hometown .. here I only want to save name... when it comes to education.. I want to save.. school, concentration and type.. I have no idea on how to achieve this..

Looking forward for help! thanks!

Comment: are you accidentally posting somebody's (with user name MyName) Facebook information? Probably better to change to some test user.

Answer (score 0):

To show the hash in a pretty-printed way, use the gem '[awesome_print](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print)'.
Add this to your Gemfile:

`gem 'awesome_print'`

And then run:
`bundle install`

And then, in your view, you can add:
`<%= ap @hello %>`

The question of how to store in the database requires a little more information on what you plan to do with it, but at minimum you could create a model, add a 'facebook_data' (type would be 'text') on that model, and then serialize it (add this line near the top of your model file: `serialize :facebook_data`).  Then you could assign the hash (`@hello` in this case) to the model's 'facebook_data' property, and then save the model. But you won't be able to query your database for individual attributes of this facebook data very easily this way.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! The way I plan to save to my database is.. lets say for a user model, i want to save to database as :facebook_id, :facebook_name, :facebook_firstname, ...., :facebook_hometown .. here I only want to save name... when it comes to education.. I want to save.. school, concentration and type.. I have no idea on how to achieve this.. Would be really grateful if you could help me with an answer!

Comment: sure, that's just the normal rails model stuff.  So you'd create, say, an Education model in rails, with school, concentration and school_type fields (the 'type' field name is best avoided as it's used internally by rails): `rails generate model education school:string concentration:string school_type:string`. Then migrate your db: `rake db:migrate`.  In your code, you can just create a new Education model and assign it those values: `ed = Education.new(school:@hello['education'][0]['school'])` etc.  You should look over Rails models and associations too

Comment: here's a link to the rails guides for models and associations: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

you can just do `@hello["name"]`  then it will give you the value of the name

Answer (score 0):

Your `@hello` object should be of the class `Koala::Facebook::API::GraphCollection` or something similar. You should be able to loop through this object, like your question demonstrates. As for what code to put inside your loop that will help you save records to the database, assuming your rails user model class name is `User`, try something like this:

```
@hello.each do |h|
  u = User.where(:facebook_id => h["id"]).first_or_initialize
  u.update_attributes(
    :name => h["name"],
    :first_name => h["first_name"],
    :hometown_city => h["hometown"]["name"].split(",").first,
    :hometown_state => h["hometown"]["name"].split(",").last.strip
    # ETC, ETC
  )
end
```

In the case of the hometown and education fields, you're just going to have to traverse the ruby hash the proper way. See the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html) for more info.